# How to draw circles one inside the other and color the segments with various colors in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, python-turtle

I would like to draw multiple circles, one inside the other, divide their borders in N equal parts, and color each part of every circle with a specific color, like in the following image:
[circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nswPN.png)
(Unfortunately, here is shown only one circle. I would like to draw multiple circles, one inside the other, in this manner.)

How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you're looking for is `Nested pie charts`. You can try something like [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/nested_pie.html) from `matplotlib`.

[image]

An example is borrowed from [here](https://medium.com/@kvnamipara/a-better-visualisation-of-pie-charts-by-matplotlib-935b7667d77f).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
# Data to plot
labels = ['Python', 'C++', 'Ruby', 'Java']
sizes = [504, 337, 415, 280]
labels_gender = ['Man','Woman','Man','Woman','Man','Woman','Man','Woman']
sizes_gender = [315,189,125,212,270,145,190,90]
weight_gender = [189,315,270,212,125,145,200,80]
colors = ['#ff6666', '#ffcc99', '#99ff99', '#66b3ff']
colors_gender = ['#c2c2f0','#ffb3e6', '#c2c2f0','#ffb3e6', '#c2c2f0','#ffb3e6', '#c2c2f0','#ffb3e6']
 
# Plot
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=colors, startangle=90,frame=True)
plt.pie(sizes_gender,colors=colors_gender,radius=0.75,startangle=90)
centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0),0.5,color='black', fc='white',linewidth=0)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)
 
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]